# Set language only for some sentences

Tags: languages

I'm working in a document with these specifics:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}


\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%============================================================
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
%============================================================
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{alltt}
```

There is the possibility to write some sentences in Italian languages in the text with a kind of "*italian box*"?  Any idea?

Comment: `\usepackage[italian,british]{babel}` and then `\begin{otherlanguage*}{italian}testo in italiano\end{otherlanguage*}`. Unrelated: remove the call of the `ae` package: it has been obsolete for several years and has several limitations. Also `subfigure` has been deprecated: load `subfig` or, better, `subcaption`. Both require syntax changes, but they are definitely better (the second one is recommended).

Comment: @egreg really thank you for all your advices. The solution that you proposed works properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You first of all have to announce `babel` you want to use Italian in your document, so do

```
\usepackage[italian,british]{babel}
```

that still makes British English the default language for the document.

You now have available several possibilities:

1. `\selectlanguage{italian}`, which sets Italian as the default language from the point of declaration on, respecting grouping.
2. `\begin{otherlanguage}{italian}...\end{otherlanguage}`, that's the same as before, but limits the scope of the language change.
3. `\begin{otherlanguage*}{italian}...\end{otherlanguage*}`, much similar to the above, but doesn't change the meaning of tags such as `\abstractname` or `\chaptername`.
4. `\foreignlanguage{italian}{frase in italiano}` for short inserts.

The main application you have in mind, perhaps, is for the abstract. So you can do (under `\frontmatter`, in order to have unnumbered chapters that go in the table of contents nonetheless)

```
\chapter{\abstractname}

The abstract in English.

\begin{otherlanguage}{italian}
\chapter{\abstractname}

Il sunto in italiano.
\end{otherlanguage}
```

Inside the document `otherlanguage*` is probably the environment you'll choose.

---

Some notes about your preamble.

1. The package `ae` is obsolete; don't load it.
2. Also `subfigure` is deprecated. Its official substitute is `subfig`, but it's more recommended to load `subcaption`. Both require syntax changes (check the manuals), but are better and, especially `subcaption`, more powerful.
3. Whenever I see a table using `\multirow`, I always find a better way to make it without the command. But this is personal opinion. `;-)

Here's a polished up version:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{multirow} % please! ;-)
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{alltt}
```

Comment: I tried all these but the language changes on the whole document. I am trying to write some dedications in greek and `\begin{otherlanguage}{italian}...\end{otherlanguage}` does affect the language of the whole thesis.

Comment: @seralouk There must be something else, because this doesn't normally happen.